# Could not load asset as non content

Tags: c#, xamarin, mono, xna, monogame

Im trying to load a png file as a test 2d texture. I'm receiving the error

> "Could not load testTexture asset as a non-content file!".

I'm loading the png by the Pipline.MacOS application. I've set the platform MacOS and rebuilt it. After building its put in the default Content folder. In the code I've set the root directory to the content folder, then I add the 2d texture. When I run it I get the error

> "Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentLoadException" - Could not
>   load testTexture asset as a non-content file!

I've checked all the usual things like the platform targeted being correct(this is for MacOS). I'm not sure what else to try and check. I'm using xamarin studio with mono and not the xamarin.mac (mono is free to build). Any help would be great thanks.

```
public Game1 ()
{
    graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager (this);
    Content.RootDirectory = "Content";              
    graphics.IsFullScreen = true;       
}

protected override void LoadContent ()
{
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch (GraphicsDevice);
    texture = this.Content.Load<Texture2D> ("testTexture");
}
```

Comment: have you checked this link http://www.xnadevelopment.com/tutorials/creatinga2dsprite/CreatingA2DSprite.shtml

Comment: @MethodMan I've done everything that this tutorial does. I feel like the issue is with preparing the texture with the pipeline, but I don't know what else I could do after everything I've mentioned.

Comment: did you do a google search on the error msg..? here is one link I found doing just that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25276539/could-not-load-asset-as-a-non-content-file

Comment: @MethodMan yes I've looked at this. After some more looking it seems that a few months ago xamarin studio didn't have the auto linking working. I'm trying to auto add the files now to see if this will work.

Comment: I don't know anything about building for MacOS but have you looked in your output folder for the XNB files?

Comment: @craftworkgames yeah they are there. If you read the answer I explain what the issue was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems the issue is with xamarin studio. After preparing the texture through the pipeline, it seems that xamarin hasn't fixed its bug for auto linking the new content with the Content.mgcb subfile/folder. Either that or I've somehow done something wrong. Either way it seems that you have to manually add the file to the folder in the ide. (FYI this doesn't seem to be a issue if your using Visual Studio).